# Can I take a photo of a QR code in iOS and make a game from that QR code itself?

Tags: ios, maze

So I'd like to be able to make an iOS app where a user snaps a photo of any QR code and then the app populates the photo of the QR code with a minotaur, objects, etc., making the photo "live," so to speak, so they can play the old game Minotaur, just using the QR code. The idea would be to dynamically populate any QR code with objects and a minotaur following some logic (game rules). Is this possible? Or if not, how would it be possible to make a minotaur-like maze game using preinstalled QR codes? Thanks for the assist.

Comment: This question is extremely vague and broad. Sure, such a thing is possible. Whether it's feasible for the amount of resources you are willing to commit is something else entirely. Try setting up something basic and then asking specific questions when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can take a picture of anything you want. There's nothing special about a QR code. Once you have an image of it, you should be able to do whatever you feel like doing with it. You'll obviously need to write a custom image processing library to turn the QR code into a maze, but that's besides the point of whether it's possible.